# Data grid Rows selection count Incorrect

Tags: vmware-clarity

I have selected few rows from data grid (say the selected count becomes 5)and then refreshed the page, the count of selected rows still remains the same.

Comment: Hi there. I’d love to take a look at this but I need to see your code. Could you (re)create this issue in a stackblitz? http://stackblitz.com/@clr-team

Comment: Are you refreshing the list without cleaning the selected array? Usually the rows lose the selected tick but the count still reflects the lost selected rows.